# Simple delay functions for TI Launchpad?

Tags: arm, delay, texas-instruments

In Atmel Microcontrollers, there are simple delay functions such as `__delay_ms()` and `__delay_us()` found in `utils\delay.h`.

I am using a Tiva™ C Series TM4C1294 development board, with a TM4C1294NCPDT microcontroller. However, I can't find any libraries to do similar delay functions.

Will I have to write my own delay function? I know it's not that hard, but I'd rather use an existing library if there is is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

/* Delay cycles for 1 second */
SysCtlDelay(16000000u / 3u);

Comment: What header file is this function located in?

Comment: If you're using CCS, CTRL + SHIFT + O should add the necessary header.

Comment: SysCtlDelay located in sysctl.h tivaware library.

Answer (score 0):

I test 1 second with this:

```
SysCtlDelay(SysCtlClockGet() / 3); // delay 1 second
```

The SysCtlDelay is implemented by assembly code

```
          SysCtlDelay():
000008f0:   1E40                subs       r0, r0, #1
000008f2:   D1FD                bne        SysCtlDelay
000008f4:   4770                bx         lr
```